# can one load reasonml es6 modules without a bundler

Tags: reason, bucklescript

I am trying to use my VSCODDE liver server: https://github.com/ritwickdey/vscode-live-server for development without having to run a (parceljs would be my favorite, since it has hot loading, but it is having issues with reasonml).

This almost works, but the the bucklescript compiler expects that the the node-modules to be on the path, and it appears bundlers find them, but not if one does a load this way:

### es5index.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset=utf-8>
  <link rel=stylesheet href="./style.css">
  <title>Web Data Client</title>
  <script src="../src/client/App.bs.js" type=module></script>
</head>

<body>
  <div id="index"></div>
</body>

</html>
```

This is the error I get:

```
ncaught TypeError: Failed to resolve module specifier "react". Relative references must start with either "/", "./", or "../".
```

which is to be expected since BSB created this in

### App.bs.js

```
import * as $$Array from "./../../node_modules/bs-platform/lib/es6/array.js";
import * as Block from "./../../node_modules/bs-platform/lib/es6/block.js";
import * as Curry from "./../../node_modules/bs-platform/lib/es6/curry.js";
import * as React from "react";
import * as Glamor from "./../../node_modules/bs-glamor/src/glamor.js";
import * as Js_exn from "./../../node_modules/bs-platform/lib/es6/js_exn.js";
import * as Js_dict from "./../../node_modules/bs-platform/lib/es6/js_dict.js";
import * as Js_json from "./../../node_modules/bs-platform/lib/es6/js_json.js";
import * as ReactDOMRe from "./../../node_modules/reason-react/src/ReactDOMRe.js";
import * as Caml_option from "./../../node_modules/bs-platform/lib/es6/caml_option.js";
import * as ReasonReact from "./../../node_modules/reason-react/src/ReasonReact.js";
import * as Editor$Webdataclient from "./Editor.bs.js";
import * as Loader$Webdataclient from "./Loader.bs.js";
import * as Mutations$Webdataclient from "./Mutations.bs.js";
```

now if the imports had were from the ../node-modules/* folder, I think all would work

### bsconfig.json file:

```
// This is the configuration file used by BuckleScript's build system bsb. 
// Its documentation lives here: http://bucklescript.github.io/bucklescript/docson/#build-schema.json
{
  "name": "webdataclient",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "sources": [
    {
      "dir": "src",
      "subdirs": true
    }
  ],
  "package-specs": {
    "module": "es6-global",
    "in-source": true
  },
  "suffix": ".bs.js",
  "namespace": true,
  "reason": {
    "react-jsx": 2
  },
  "refmt": 3,
  "ppx-flags": [
    "graphql_ppx/ppx"
  ],
  "bs-dependencies": [
    "reason-react",
    "bs-fetch",
    "bs-glamor"
  ]
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It doesn't look like BuckleScript can import external JavaScript modules with `es6-global`, including React. [The relevant GitHub issue is here](https://github.com/BuckleScript/bucklescript/issues/2118).

The problem is that BuckleScript currently has no way of knowing the path to the JavaScript file that `"react"` is supposed to resolve to. BuckleScript knows the paths to the modules it compiles, so they work fine. But it doesn't know anything about externals, so it outputs their paths as-is.